# Form saving does not work

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to save a ModelForm as I did a thousand times before, but I'm not getting it to work. This is my Test class:

```
class FooForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
```

Now I simple get an object and save it:

```
a = Account.objects.all()[0]
a.save()
```

This works. Now I want to pass this object to the form and save it:

```
f = FooForm(instance=a)
f.is_valid()
```

... gives False. Even no errors are stored:

```
f.errors
{}
f.non_field_errors()
[]
```

Saving throws an error then:

```
f.save()
>>> AttributeError: 'FooForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'
```

Any ideas?

[UPDATE]

Regarding to second's comment:

```
f = Form(data={}, instance=a)
f.save()
[....]
ValueError: The Account could not be changed because the data didn't validate.
f.is_valid()
>>> False
f.errors
{'user': [u'This field is required.']}
>>> a.user
<User: demo>
```

BTW the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) says, passing without data is okay, then you pass an instance:

```
# Create a form to edit an existing Article.
>>> a = Article.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> f = ArticleForm(instance=a)
>>> f.save()
```

... and could anyone please clarify the downvote? I think it's not such a strange topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing an instance to a `ModelForm` merely provides default values for the form. The form *still* expects POST data. You've given it none.

**EDIT BASED ON UPDATE**:

By passing an empty dataset, you've essentially reset everything to empty. Again, `instance` merely provides the default values for the form to display when it's first rendered. It doesn't have *any* impact on what final values the form will be saved with. That's where `data` comes in.

Try:

```
f = FooForm(data=a.__dict__, instance=a)
f.is_valid()
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Basically, this seems to work, but not for ForeignKeys, as "user" is in my Account-Model. I think this behaviour is suboptimal; I will have to implement another solution. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

the form constructor needs a `data` argument (typically `request.POST`)

**update**

what are you actually trying to do? if you just want to change your instance in code, you don't need a form at all.

Comment: now your error should speak for itself. the `user` field is required, so you have to pass in a user (id)

Comment: Well, then I don't understand the option to pass an instance, as the documentation suggests, since the instance has "user" attached. Regarding your comment: This is a test setting. Actually, I want to perform an object update with a lot of data and custom validation that already exists in my form.

Comment: Passing the instance sets the initial values for the fields (when rendered onto a page) to what is currently set on the model. I think the `form.save()` in the docs is a mistake in the docs themselves; AFAIK that shouldn't work.

Comment: Just a side-note - if you're converting a complex "normal" form to a model form, I've found that that's generally not worth the effort. Just write the extra code to modify an instance directly from the non-ModelForm's .cleaned_data.

Answer (score 1):

A form without data passed in is never valid, since there is no data, it also has no errors, since `django.forms.BaseForm.full_clean` (the method that is responsible for populating `cleaned_data`, `errors` and `non_field_errors`) doesn't actually do anything if there is no data (`is_bound` is `False` since there's no `data` or `files`).

So pass in data (a dictionary or dictionary-like-object, such as `request.POST`) into the form as first argument, then check `is_valid` again.